# MySQL error code 1050

Tags: mysql

i am having this odd error when i try to run this code (1050 table already exist)
Here is my code,

```
USE gc200352712;

CREATE TABLE movies (
title VARCHAR(50),
year INT,
length INT,
url VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO movies VALUES
('Everest', 2015, 121, 'http://www.everestmovie.com'), 
('Black Mass', 2015, 122, 'http://www.blackmassthemovie.com'),
('Steve Jobs', 2015, 122, 'http://www.stevejobsthefilm.com');
```

select * from movies;

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty descriptive and accurate.

You can't create another table with the same name if it already exists in the database. So after you execute that complete set of queries for the first time you need to drop the `CREATE TABLE` part on subsequent executions in order for the `INSERT` part to work.